# No Space left on device - Fedora 15

Tags: linux, disk-space-utilization

I am running Fedora15 and have the following message:
No space left on device when saving files, unzipping etc..

I check my disk usage and got the following result:

```
[root@aquanes mapper]# df -k
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
rootfs                46968816   6730528  39768244  15% /
udev                   1536804         0   1536804   0% /dev
tmpfs                  1544600      1180   1543420   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                  1544600       704   1543896   1% /run
/dev/mapper/vg_aquanes-lv_root
                      46968816   6730528  39768244  15% /
tmpfs                  1544600         0   1544600   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                  1544600       704   1543896   1% /var/lock
tmpfs                  1544600       704   1543896   1% /var/run
tmpfs                  1544600         0   1544600   0% /media
/dev/sda1               508745     90135    393010  19% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg_aquanes-lv_home
                      44866044  42617820       340 100% /home


[root@aquanes mapper]# df -i

Filesystem            Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
rootfs               2940928  161388 2779540    6% /

udev                  210625     475  210150    1% /dev
tmpfs                 214523      10  214513    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                 214523     485  214038    1% /run
/dev/mapper/vg_aquanes-lv_root
                     2940928  161388 2779540    6% /
tmpfs                 214523      11  214512    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                 214523     485  214038    1% /var/lock
tmpfs                 214523     485  214038    1% /var/run
tmpfs                 214523       1  214522    1% /media
/dev/sda1             128016      47  127969    1% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg_aquanes-lv_home
                     2809856   69402 2740454    3% /home
```

Looks like my home directory is full but when I run the disk Usage Analyzer tool I have still plenty of space left:

Total file system capacity:88.1 GB (Used 47.1GB available: 40.9GB).

Bit confused here on the way the partition uses the space. Could someone let me know how to get around this space issue?

Thanks!

Comment: If you ran the analyzer as non-root, it may not have been able to read files inside of some directories. It is also possible that files have been deleted, but remain open by programs. This question is off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/home is near 100% full. It appears to only have 340k available.  If you are trying to use more than 340k of space, I'd guess this is the problem.  You didn't say which filesystem you were trying to write to, but none of the ones listed here appear to be the one described by `Total file system capacity:88.1 GB (Used 47.1GB available: 40.9GB).`

Comment: I agree. The Total file system capacity:88.1 GB (Used 47.1GB available: 40.9GB). That's for my home directory, and I am trying to write to home. I don't do anything as root other than admin tasks.

If my home directory is full and I am using only 15% (6 GB) of 46968816KB (44 GB) as root. How can I relocate the memory from root to my user? Looks like 14 GB would be enough for root and I could relocate 30GB to my home?

Thanks

Comment: since they are both on lvm, do the vg they are on have free extents?

Comment: and if not, what filesystem types are these?

Comment: `vgdisplay /dev/vg_aquanes
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               vg_aquanes
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  4
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
 ...
  VG Size               92.66 GiB
  PE Size               32.00 MiB
  Total PE              2965
  Alloc PE / Size       2965 / 92.66 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0   
  VG UUID               TKcBLO-wOgC-hfCG-BkE4-EfZZ-SwUt-OKeoCr `

Comment: > vgdisplay /dev/vg_aquanes
>   --- Volume group ---
>   VG Name               vg_aquanes
>  System ID             
>   Format                lvm2
>   Metadata Areas        1
>   Metadata Sequence No  4
>   VG Access             read/write
>   VG Status             resizable
  
>   Act PV                1
>   VG Size               92.66 GiB
>   PE Size               32.00 MiB
>   Total PE              2965
>   Alloc PE / Size       2965 / 92.66 GiB
>   Free  PE / Size       0 / 0   
>   VG UUID               TKcBLO-wOgC-hfCG-BkE4-EfZZ-SwUt-OKeoCr 'code'
What's the next step?

Comment: You'll have to boot to some other medium like a livecd, resize the / filesystem, shring the lv containing /, grow the lv containing /home, resize /home.  you'd use resize2fs to resize the filesystems if these are ext2/3/4.  This stuff is rather dangerous.  have up to date backups before starting.

Answer (score 0):

Many filesystems have a feature where a certain amount of the space is reserved for root; if that's set to 15% then you'll be unable to read or write as non-root. Try writing files as root to see if you're able to do that.

The reason I suspect this problem is that 15% is a nice round number that might be a reasonable default for the amount of space reserved for the root user.

If that's the problem you can use tune2fs to view and modify that limit on ext2/3/4 filesystems.

Comment: He has 15% *in use*, not 15% left. 85% available ...

Comment: Well that's a very good point.

Comment: I count 100% used.